# Redshift move data from one table to another table

Tags: amazon-redshift, sql-insert, alter-table

```
insert into table1 select * from table2
```

tabl1 have one addition column as compare to table2.

how can i move the data of other columns from table2 to table1 without set the all columns name individually in the insert query for Redshift ?

Is there any idea ?

Comment: it is good practice to specify the column names rather than using *, that is your best approach

Comment: @JonScott There are more then 100 columns. So i can specify in query . Any other way !! Please suggest...

Comment: no other way, sorry

Comment: @JonScott Ok. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do this you have to put all extra columns at the table2 at the end of the column list and then you'll be able to set nulls or values after select star like this:

```
insert into table1
select *, null, null, null
from table2
```

Comment: But as per your way, it will insert he null values to only last columns. But i have added the column in table1 in middle somewhere. So i think, it would not work !!

Comment: @PankajKumar yes, that exactly what I mean, for the closest approximation of what you want you need to put all extra columns at the end of the column list. If you want to put an extra column in the middle you need to specify all columns individually, there's no way around